# Java FX - How to create a Label with no contents to reserve spot in Layout Manager?

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to create a Label with some type of invisible contents, to preserve it's "space" in a layout such as a HBox or VBox so as to prevent Layout Manager engaging in some type of resizing, so that if I have to set the contents of a certain Label to empty, the Layout Manager will not resize the container?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All layouts will lay out an [invisible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#visibleProperty) node as if it is visible.  You can use an invisible Label as a “strut” by making it invisible and placing it, along with your visible node, in a StackPane:

```
Label valueLabel = new Label("This may become empty");

Label strut = new Label(valueLabel.getText());
strut.setVisible(false);

StackPane labelPane = new StackPane(strut, valueLabel);

hBox.getChildren().add(labelPane);
```

Another option is to simply make your value Label invisible instead of making its text empty, but I realize there are circumstances where that may not be possible, such as if the Label’s text property is bound.

Comment: Thanks @VGR  Didn't know about the setVisible property!

Answer (score 1):

As with all `Region`s you can set [the `minWidth` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#minWidthProperty):

```
label.setMinWidth(100);
```

Which will result in the label not being resized below size `100` regardless of it's `text`.